# Missing driver in Windows 7 64-bit? (Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Integrated FlashMedia Controller)

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, 64-bit

I have Windows 7 64-bit build 7600 on my Sony VAIO VGN-AR890U laptop. In Device Manager there is a device which I've not yet found a driver for!

[image: My Device Manager]

I've followed the *Update Driver* button's instructions and below is the result, but it doesn't resolve the problem. I was searching the web for the driver but I couldn't find anything special that resolved my problem.

[image: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Integrated FlashMedia Controller]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can download the Driver from here : http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/drivers/41103d1260294739-sony-vaio-card-reader-prolem-new-7-install-tipci_xx21_xx12_03.zip

Reference :
http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/72636-missing-driver-win7-x64-texas-instruments-pcixx12.html

Answer (score 0):

Link for the driver is available here

> http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/drivers/41103d1260294739-sony-vaio-card-reader-prolem-new-7-install-tipci_xx21_xx12_03.zip

Answer (score 0):

Latest driver (version 2.0.0.20) for this device that I've found is [from Sony](http://esupport.sony.com/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=VGNCR320E&upd_id=5647). The only problem is that it uses a Wise self executing compressed installer which also checks machine compatibility. I suppose only from Sony build. **I successfully installed this driver on an HP running Windows 8.1 x64.**

The good thing is that this is just a Texas Instruments PCIxx12 FlashCard driver and can be installed on any machine from any manufacturer that has this device built in.

**I personally trust only OEM downloadable drivers so this one is directly from Sony.** I wouldn't download drivers from any third party websites as drivers have highest accessibility rights on a machine. Installing a malicious one would be catastrophic failure.

### Installation process

Knowing that this is Wise Installer file, installing it is rather easy by following these steps and knowing [command line switches](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/wise-executable-parameters) of these installers:

1. Download the driver from [Sony's website](http://esupport.sony.com/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=VGNCR320E&upd_id=5647)
2. Open elevated command prompt
3. Change folder to file dlownloaded location (usually `%USERPROFILE%/Downloads`)
4. Create a folder i.e. `TIDriver`
5. Execute this command (assuming downloaded executable's name is `TIDMSC-16368200-1042.exe`)

   ```
   TIDMSC-16368200-1042.exe /x TIDriver
   ```

   This will extract contents of this Wise Installer to specified folder - in this case it was `TIDriver`
6. Open Device Manager
7. Right click on your *Mass Storage Device* missing a driver and select **Update Driver Software**
8. Choose **Browse my computer for driver software** and point it to your specified folder.
9. Confirm and you should have driver installed and card reader working without any issues.

*Voila.*